# Expand Grid With Unknown Number of Vectors - R

Tags: r, function, data-structures, combinations

I have this for loop which creates a new data frame in every iteration. Let's call them df1, df2, df3 ... dfn.

Since I do not know the 'n' term, by hoping that n is not beyond my imagination & patience combined, I am using expand.grid like this:

```
if (n == 1) {
  matrix = df1
} else if (n == 2) {
  matrix = expand.grid(df1, df2)
} else if (n ==3) {
  matrix = expand.grid(df1, df2, df3)
} else if (n ==4) {
  matrix = expand.grid(df1, df2, df3, df4)
} else if (n ==5) {
  matrix = expand.grid(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
}
```

...and it goes like that...

Is there a more convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't fully understand the setup you work in. In case you already have all the data.frames in your environment (and assuming no other object has 'df' in its name) a somewhat hacky solution may be to count the number of data.frames using `sum(grepl("df", ls()))`.

Comment: What kind of objects are df1, df2, df3...? You say you create them, but your code shows you use them to create `matrix`. A reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the best way to do the same operation on multiple objects is to put them in a list. Once you've got the data arranged in this way, `do.call` can be used, so you might end up with something like:

```
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5) 
matrix <- do.call(expand.grid, dfs[1:n])
```

In the specific case of `expand.grid`, the functionality is built in, so that you can just do

```
matrix <- expand.grid(dfs[1:n])
```

Note that if `df1...` really are data.frames, your code and this code produce a warning and possibly unexpected results. To avoid the warning `df1...` should be vectors.